# How to add a TextView to a LinearLayout dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I try to add a `TextView` to a `LinearLayout` dynamically such as in the following code, but it doesn't appear when I run the application?

```
setContentView(R.layout.advanced);

m_vwJokeLayout=(LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.m_vwJokeLayout);
m_vwJokeEditText=(EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.m_vwJokeEditText);
m_vwJokeButton=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.m_vwJokeButton);

TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setText("test");
this.m_vwJokeLayout.addView(tv);
```

What's the problem?

Comment: <LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/m_vwJokeLayout" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></LinearLayout>

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
tv.setText("test");
this.m_vwJokeLayout.addView(tv);
```

You can change **lparams** according to your needs

Answer (score 61):

Here is a more general answer for future viewers of this question. The layout we will make is below:

[image]

### Method 1: Add TextView to existing LinearLayout

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dynamic_linearlayout);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_example);

    // Add textview 1
    TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
    textView1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textView1.setText("programmatically created TextView1");
    textView1.setBackgroundColor(0xff66ff66); // hex color 0xAARRGGBB
    textView1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);// in pixels (left, top, right, bottom)
    linearLayout.addView(textView1);

    // Add textview 2
    TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10); // (left, top, right, bottom)
    textView2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    textView2.setText("programmatically created TextView2");
    textView2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
    textView2.setBackgroundColor(0xffffdbdb); // hex color 0xAARRGGBB
    linearLayout.addView(textView2);
}
```

Note that for `LayoutParams` you must specify the kind of layout for the import, as in

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
```

Otherwise you need to use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` in the code.

Here is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_example"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff99ccff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

### Method 2: Create both LinearLayout and TextView programmatically

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // NOTE: setContentView is below, not here

    // Create new LinearLayout
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xff99ccff);

    // Add textviews
    TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
    textView1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textView1.setText("programmatically created TextView1");
    textView1.setBackgroundColor(0xff66ff66); // hex color 0xAARRGGBB
    textView1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20); // in pixels (left, top, right, bottom)
    linearLayout.addView(textView1);

    TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10); // (left, top, right, bottom)
    textView2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    textView2.setText("programmatically created TextView2");
    textView2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
    textView2.setBackgroundColor(0xffffdbdb); // hex color 0xAARRGGBB
    linearLayout.addView(textView2);

    // Set context view
    setContentView(linearLayout);
}
```

### Method 3: Programmatically add one xml layout to another xml layout

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dynamic_linearlayout);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_linearlayout_item, null);
    FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flContainer);
    container.addView(view);
}
```

Here is dynamic_linearlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

And here is the dynamic_linearlayout_item.xml to add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_example"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff99ccff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff66ff66"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:text="programmatically created TextView1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffdbdb"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="10px"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="programmatically created TextView2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add import  android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

Answer (score 9):

I customized more @Suragch code. My output looks

[image]

I wrote a method to stop code redundancy.

```
public TextView createATextView(int layout_widh, int layout_height, int align,
        String text, int fontSize, int margin, int padding) {

    TextView textView_item_name = new TextView(this);

    // LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
    // LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    // layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            layout_widh, layout_height);

    _params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
    _params.addRule(align);
    textView_item_name.setLayoutParams(_params);

    textView_item_name.setText(text);
    textView_item_name.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize);
    textView_item_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    // textView1.setBackgroundColor(0xff66ff66); // hex color 0xAARRGGBB
    textView_item_name.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    return textView_item_name;

}
```

It can be called like

```
createATextView(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,
            subTotal.toString(), 20, 10, 20);
```

Now you can add this to a RelativeLayout dynamically. LinearLayout is also same, just add a orientation.

```
    RelativeLayout primary_layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    LayoutParams layoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    primary_layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParam);

    // FOR LINEAR LAYOUT SET ORIENTATION
    // primary_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    // FOR BACKGROUND COLOR 
    primary_layout.setBackgroundColor(0xff99ccff);

    primary_layout.addView(createATextView(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, list[i],
            20, 10, 20));
    primary_layout.addView(createATextView(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,
            subTotal.toString(), 20, 10, 20));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
TextView rowTextView = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourTextView, null);
        rowTextView.setText(text);
        layout.addView(rowTextView);
```

This is how I'm using this:

```
 private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();


if(tags.isEmpty()){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Tag>>() {
        }.getType();
        tags = gson.fromJson(tour.getTagsJSONArray(), listType);
    }



if (flowLayout != null) {
        if(!tags.isEmpty()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "setTags: "+ flowLayout.getChildCount() );
            flowLayout.removeAllViews();
            for (Tag tag : tags) {
                FlowLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                lparams.setMargins(PixelUtil.dpToPx(this, 0), PixelUtil.dpToPx(this, 5), PixelUtil.dpToPx(this, 10), PixelUtil.dpToPx(this, 5));// llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
                TextView rowTextView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tag, null);
                rowTextView.setText(tag.getLabel());
                rowTextView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                flowLayout.addView(rowTextView);
            }
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "setTags: after "+ flowLayout.getChildCount() );
    }
```

And this is my custom TextView named tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
android:textSize="10dp"
android:textAllCaps="true"
fontPath="@string/font_light"
android:background="@drawable/tag_shape"
android:paddingLeft="11dp"
android:paddingTop="6dp"
android:paddingRight="11dp"
android:paddingBottom="6dp">
```

this is my tag_shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#f2f2f2" />
<corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

efect:

[image]

In other place I'm adding textviews with language names from dialog with listview:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Explain your answer please!

Answer (score 1):

**layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layoutTest"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      >
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**class file**:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_dynamic);
layoutTest=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutTest);
TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

textView.setText("testDynamic textView");
layoutTest.addView(textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linearlayout. its params should be "wrap_content" to add dynamic data in your layout xml. if you use match or fill parent then you cannot see the output.

It Should be like this.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **kotlin**, you can use a custom layout for each item.

Step 1: Create a custom XML layout file. *Here named as 'custom_content_item'.*

Step 2: Create a linear layout in the main layout in which you want to add dynamic layouts. *Here names as 'content_linearLayout'.*

Step 3: Use below code for adding dynamic layouts.

```
val linearLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.content_linearLayout)

linearLayout.removeAllViews()

for (contentModel in course_content_list) {
    val contentView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_content_item, null)

    // Find and populate custom views
    val contentTitle = contentView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.content_title)
    contentTitle.text = contentModel.title

    // Add the custom view to the LinearLayout
    linearLayout.addView(contentView)
}
```