# Want to add textviews to LinearLayout in an existing layout.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I can't quite get this to work, hoping to get some hints, it seems like from my research the code should work, any thoughts would be greatly appreciated...

I have an existing layout.xml file that includes:

```
<RelativeLayout style="@style/bodyLayout">
    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false"
    >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollLinearLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >           

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I have programatic code as follows:

```
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollLinearLayout);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setId(1);
    tv.setTextSize(R.dimen.text_size_medium);
    tv.setText("test");
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    ll.addView(tv);
```

The new TextView doesn't appear when the activity is displayed, I know I a missing something obvious... the new TextView should appear in the LinearLayout section...

Comment: this link can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203506/how-can-i-add-a-textview-to-a-linearlayout-dynamically-in-android/27781046#27781046

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run your code works fine

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.subLinear);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setId(1);
    tv.setTextSize(15);
    tv.setText("test adding");
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    ll.addView(tv);
```

if you add new View(anything) from any button click event then add this line

```
ll.invalidate();
```

it will refresh it your component

Comment: Thanks for the followup, the problem ended up being this line in my code: **LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);** After removing that line, everything worked well. Thanks for testing and confirming my code, and the tip on the ll.invalidate(); Cheers.

Comment: In follow up that wasn't the issue (seemed strange which is why I checked further), I tested variations on this, but it seems to be related to using **R.dimen.text_size_medium** instead of a straight numeric value. In the dimens file the value is stated as 18sp, which doesn't translate over as a proper parameter to the setTextSize method... entering a straight value works. Going to have to research this more, I would rather pull values from my xml resources as opposed to hardcoding values...

Comment: This seemed to work:   tv.setTextSize(this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.text_size_medium)); Cheers

Comment: Or more simply... **tv.setTextSize(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(‌​R.dimen.text_size_medium));** also works...