# How to add a textview to layout at runtime when a Toggle button is clicked in the same Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

How to add a textview to layout at runtime when a Toggle button is clicked in the same Layout???

Comment: have you searched for "add textview dynamically". if so you may have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203506/how-can-i-add-a-textview-to-a-linearlayout-dynamically-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably would be easier to just show/hide it. Use `setVisibility(value)`, value could be `View.GONE`, `View.INVISIBLE` or `View.VISIBLE`.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an example:

(On button Click)

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout)
TextView txt1 = new TextView(MyClass.this);
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
linearLayout.addView(txt1);
```

Comment: hey thanks fr the info i also need the textview to be vanished when i click the toggle to off state