# How to create(or add) and populate new layout into a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I use fragment and i want to retieve datas into database and show theses datas into layout created in the code.

there's the code:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {


  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rssitem_detail, container, false);

    return view;
  }
```

there's the actual layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_all"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout_fiche"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@drawable/single_border">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detailsText_fiche"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:text="Zone de Fiche"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
    </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

I want add many layaout below the TextView id:detailsText_fiche. How can i do?

thanx in advance,

Comment: ListAdapter and Bind your data to the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement it programmatically, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203506/how-can-i-add-a-textview-to-a-linearlayout-dynamically-in-android), to see how to do it.