# Android : How to adjust Textview

Tags: android, button, textview

Hello i am trying to display the content i receive in an activity using `TextView` but it seems that `TextView` is overlapping a button that i have put in activity's UI.My goal is to put `TextView` and the button side by side. I have put the `TextView` in the UI dynamically like this:

```
String display = extras.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE");


    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setWidth(20);
    textView.setHeight(20);
    textView.setText(display);

    setContentView(textView);
```

I know i miss something but i cant find what it is,so can you please suggest a way how to fix that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setContentView(textView);` it changes your `layout` to just the `textView` so it isn't overlapping your `Button` but your `Button` isn't shown anymore. You need to add it to your `layout` and put it where you want it.

You can do this by getting a reference to your root `View` in your xml and calling `addView(textVie)` on that root `View` and use `addRule()` to position your `TextView` where you want. However, if it isn't necessary to add your `TextView` dynamically then it is much easier to declare it in your xml.

If you do want to add it dynamically still, then [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203506/how-can-i-add-a-textview-to-a-linearlayout-dynamically-in-android), and many more, covers it.

Comment: thank you very much for you help :) do you know where i can find a solution for this using the xml way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What part don't you know how to do? Create a `TextView` as you have your `Button`, create a reference to it and initialize it like you would, then call `setText()` on it

Comment: sorry silly question ! i am very new to android development and i am easily confused:P anyway thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: No problem...it happens. I still get confused