# Get total value from list of textview

Tags: java, android

I want to get total of amount in a textview as shown below.

[image]

```
  // List of Amount
  for(t=0;t<pname.length;t++) {
      newRow = (TableRow) new TableRow(this);
      float val1= Float.parseFloat(price);
      float val2= Float.parseFloat(rate);
      String resultamount = Float.toString(val2- val1);
      Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(resultamount);

      ilist[a]=(TextView) new TextView(this);
      ilist[a].setText(String.format("%.2f", value1));  
  }
```

I have created another tablerow outside of for loop to get the total value. 
I am now confused how to get the total from the list. 
I tried but I am getting the last value of the list as total.

Comment: Are you dynamically adding TextView?

Comment: yes i am adding textview dynamically to the table layout

Answer (score 0):

First change

```
String resultamount = Float.toString(val2- val1);
Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(resultamount);
```

To

```
double value1 = (double)(val2- val1);
```

*It has nothing to do with the answer it just strange code...*

To access it outside the list, make it class member, or static, or any other way that will allow you to access it.

Comment: Only the last value of the list is displayed

Comment: @Learner I don't understand your comment. Is it a new question?

Comment: no @Babibu - I want to get the total amount from the list to be displayed. I am only getting the last row of the list as total

Answer (score 0):

you have not passed the `layoutParam` for the new TextView. You are setting the value in the TextView object.

[See this for dynamic addition of textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203506/how-can-i-add-a-textview-to-a-linearlayout-dynamically-in-android)

Currently, your textview is unknown about the textview. You need to tell your layout that you want to add new textview to it.

Comment: Hi i have textview added to the layout and that is working well. My question here is how to get the list of amount value