# Add TextView to LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I defined textview in xml and i try to add textview to linearlayout programmatically 10 times.

This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView htext;
    private LinearLayout linearlayout;

    public void init()

    {
        linearlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.itemLayout0);
        htext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hText0);
    }

    private void addtext() {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

            htext.setText(i + "");
            linearlayout.addView(htext);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
        addtext();
    }
}
```

And Xml

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/itemLayout0"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="89dp"
android:background="@drawable/title_background"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hText0"
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="No data"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


     </LinearLayout>
```

Bu it doesnt work. I think the problem is

```
linearlayout.addView(htext);
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: do you want to add text 10 times?

Comment: Thank you for your help, l have solved via your answers.

Comment: This link Can help u:

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203506/how-can-i-add-a-textview-to-a-linearlayout-dynamically-in-android/27781046#27781046

Answer (score 6):

Create `TextView` dynamically like

```
 TextView htext =new TextView(this);
 htext.setText("Test");
 htext.setId(5);
 htext.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

and then add to Layout

```
 linearlayout.addView(htext);
```

Comment: Add LayoutParams maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `TextView` you are adding is already in the View hierarchy and has its layout parameters set, so when you call `linearLayout.addView(htext);` it references the same `TextView` that is already added in the .xml file.

You need to create a new instance of `TextView` and add it to the View hierarchy, using `addView()` method, like M D wrote.