# Cannot append TextView with exixting one dynamically

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite

friends I am building an App for android and facing some problem in showing dynamically added `TextViewer` my scenario is like this.
I am using `ResulReceiver` to receive `notification` and adding this result Dynamically in `TextView` to display.When my activity is active `I.e The application is keep open`  till then it is working properly. 
When my Activity is not in the `Active` mode then I'm storing it to `DB (SQLLITE)`, but when I come back to my Activity again then I can fetch data from DB and do the same thing like before,till now there is no problem.
But it starts as i receive new notification at that time is not able to append the new `TextView` with the existing one dynamically,But when fro debugging purpose i use Toast it is showing properly.
Could you please help me out.
Thanks in Advance.
**This is my code**

```
 @Override
    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String result = resultData.getString("notifyService");
        CustomActionBar.controlNotifyImage(this,mActionBar);
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if(!".activity.CatagoryChooserActivity".equals(componentInfo.getShortClassName()) ){
            notifyInfo = new NotifyInfo();
            notifyInfo.setNotifyPk(100000+new Long(CreateOrderService.notifyCount.get()));
            notifyInfo.setNotifyTxt(result);
            notifyInfo.setNotifyDate(new Date().toString());
            notifyInfo.setNotifyTime(new Date().toGMTString());
            SellerNotifyDB sellerNotifydb = SellerNotifyDB.getInstance(context);
            sellerNotifydb.addNotification(notifyInfo);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Notify :: "+CreateOrderService.notifyCount.get(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
       else {
            runOnUiThread(new UpdateUI(result));
        }
    }
    class UpdateUI implements Runnable
    {
        String updateString;

        public UpdateUI(String updateString) {
            this.updateString = updateString;
        }
        public void run() {
           // txtview.setText(updateString);
            createNotifyLatout(updateString);
        }
        private void createNotifyLatout(String result) {
            //final ArrayList<TextView> addrTextList = new ArrayList<TextView>();

            addrLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dashboardLayout);
            TextView addrTextView = new TextView(context);
            LinearLayout addrLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
            addrLayout.setPadding(2, 0, 2, 0);
            addrLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ImageView editImgBtn = new ImageView(context);
            editImgBtn.setId(700 + CreateOrderService.notifyCount.get());
            editImgBtn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.takeorder));
            editImgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
            editImgBtn.setLayoutParams((new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,
                    40, 1.0f)));
            ImageView deltImgBtn = new ImageView(context);
            deltImgBtn.setId(8000 + CreateOrderService.notifyCount.get());
            deltImgBtn.setLayoutParams((new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,
                    50, 1.0f)));
            deltImgBtn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
            deltImgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
            deltImgBtn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cancelorder));
            addrTextView.setPadding(2, 5, 0, 0);

            addrTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<br><br>" + result + "<br><br>"));
            addrTextView.setLayoutParams((new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)));
            addrTextView.setMaxEms(10);
            // registerForContextMenu(addrTextView);
            addrLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.banarColor));
            addrLayout.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
            addrLayout.setDividerDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider));
            addrTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundColor));
            addrTextView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backg_txt));

            addrLayout.addView(editImgBtn);
            addrLayout.addView(deltImgBtn);
            // addrTextList.add(addrTextView);
            addrLinearLayout.addView(addrTextView);
            addrLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_img));
            addrLinearLayout.addView(addrLayout);
            Toast.makeText(context,"Notify Open :: "+CreateOrderService.notifyCount.get()+"=@@=="+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        CustomActionBar.controlNotifyImage(this,mActionBar);
        //Toast.makeText(context,"#####",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SellerNotifyDB sellerNotifydb = SellerNotifyDB.getInstance(context);
        sellerNotifydb.deleteNotification();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        CustomActionBar.controlNotifyImage(this,mActionBar);
       SellerNotifyDB sellerNotifydb = SellerNotifyDB.getInstance(context);
        ArrayList notifyInfoList = sellerNotifydb.getNotification();
        if(notifyInfoList instanceof ArrayList && notifyInfoList.size() > 0)
            for (int i=0;i<notifyInfoList.size();i++){
                //createNotifyLatout(((NotifyInfo)notifyInfoList.get(i)).getNotifyTxt());
                test = ((NotifyInfo)notifyInfoList.get(i)).getNotifyTxt();
                runOnUiThread(new UpdateUI(test));
            }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please post some code

Comment: don't use textView.setText() it will destroy the previous text and will set new text. Use textView.append("whatever");
for better understanding of the question post some code!

Comment: You want to append `text` or want to add a new `textview`?

Comment: @AshishTamrakar I have add my code please help me

Comment: @FahidNadeem I have edited my post and here is my code please help me

Comment: @smn_onrocks apparently you are setting result in  addrTextView as setText and idk 'result' keeps the new String or it appends the previous string as well. So, all you need to do is to keep track of previous string in your variable and then append it with new String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to stop your existing running service.

Comment: which one the old one or the new one??

Comment: Old one.means which is already running. You need to stop this first and again need to create new one

Answer (score 0):

Keep your Existing TextView in a LinearLayout and then generate a TextView And add to LinearLayout. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203506/how-can-i-add-a-textview-to-a-linearlayout-dynamically-in-android)