# Creating a layout Multiple times in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

How to create a whole layout (Relative/Linear)  multiple times in Android? I want the same layout to be created multiple times inside a horizontal scroll view.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203506/how-can-i-add-a-textview-to-a-linearlayout-dynamically-in-android) link should be usefull

Comment: you need to provide what you have been working on, so answerers can look at it help you with it, but what about inflating a view from resources or creating it programmatically that is hard?

Comment: Why not use a ListView or RecyclerView, with each row containing the relevant layout?

Comment: I have a relative layout containing a list view and two text views i want to dynamically create the whole relative layout dynamically for multiple times.

Comment: Can you post what you already did?

Comment: Thanks for your help .I got it by using the idea in the comment below ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RecyclerView` for Horizontal scrolling-

or-

1. Take horizontal scrollview reference in java code by `findViewById`.
2. Create one other xml for view which you want to display multiple

   time.
3. inflate that view by `getlayoutinflator`. Create a loop in
       view.
4. create a linearlayout at runtime and add those view to it by add
   view
5. and add linearlayout to horizontal scroll view. by addview()

**take a idea and modify the below code**

```
scrollview = findViewByID(scrollview);
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
for(your loop){
View v= getLayoutInflator().inflate(R.layout.xml);
ll.addView(v);
}
scrollview.addView(ll);
```

Comment: Hey got it finally using your idea.. Thanks for the idea it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Either you need to add inflated child views to the root view like below

```
RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootView);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, null);
rootView.addView(child);
```

OR you can define and **include** that layout multiple times inside other.

Check this link http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Include your reusable layout like this

```
<include
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   layout="@layout/reusabelLayout" />
```