# Adding TextViews programmatically

Tags: java, android

I have found a couple ways to do this, but my issue is that my code has to be a LinearLayout with a horizontal orientation. So what happens is the dynamically created TextViews go off the screen.

The code I have is below:

```
   mProductAttrLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
   mProductAttrLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    for (ProductAttribute productAttribute : aProductAttributes) {
      String name = productAttribute.getName();
      TextView attr = new TextView(getContext());
      attr.setText(name);
      attr.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
      attr.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      attr.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
      mProductAttrLayout.addView(attr);


      for (int i = 0; i < productAttribute.getValues().size(); i++) {
        TextView value = new TextView(getContext());
        value.setText(productAttribute.getValues().get(i));
        value.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        value.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        value.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        mProductAttrLayout.addView(value);
      }
    }
```

What I currently have is:

> | **name**: value, value, value, val--|

what I need is something like:

> **name**: value, value(unknown number of values)

but I need it to go the the next line in the screen if it's too wide like below:

> | **name**: value, value, value,---|
>
> | value, value, value. ------------|

Hope you can understand what I need?

Comment: What does "go the the next screen" mean? Your ASCII art suggests that you mean "go to the next line". In that case, I would recommend either having just one `TextView` or using something like a flow layout, of which [there are several implementations for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=flowlayout).

Comment: Use flow layout to handle multiple textview in single layout(this will work as wrap content feature of layout). https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Comment: Ok flow layout looks like the solution, but im a little lost as to how i add the views to the flow layout? is it similar to flowlayout.addView(view)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question I asked long ago but they (Google) have given us a solution to this problem using `FlexboxLayout` with the `flexWrap="wrap"` attribute.

This is for anyone else that finds this question with the same problem.

Example in XML:

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:flexWrap="wrap" />
```

For more info you can visit the github repo here [FlexboxLayout Repo](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

It works like this:

[image]

Can read more over here:

[Build flexible layouts with FlexboxLayout](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayout` is the wrong choice here.

You could either write your own layout or use existing work.

What you probably want is usually called a FlowLayout, like [this](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout).

Custom layouts can be used like any other Layout. E.g. you can add views with `layout.addView`. Noramlly the only difference in use is reflected in the custom `layoutParams`.

Comment: Thanks, i went with the FlowLayout

Answer (score 0):

Create a flow layout in OnCreate:-

```
   muscle_gp_tag_flow_layout = new FlowLayout(mContext);
   //add the flow layout to your main layout
```

Call the method first time and whenever you want to refresh the view:-

```
public void createShowSpannableStringMuscleGroup(List<MuscleGroup> muscleGroups) {

        // clears the flowlayout views
        muscle_gp_tag_flow_layout.removeAllViews();
        for (int countGroup = 0; countGroup < muscleGroups.size(); countGroup++) {
            MuscleGroup group = muscleGroups.get(countGroup);
            if (group.getName() != null && group.getName().length() > 0) {

//                inflating the textview views in flow layout
               TextView textView=new textView(context);
//set color, background for textview
              textView.setText(group.getName().toString());

//                adding views to flowlayout muscle group
                muscle_gp_tag_flow_layout.addView(mView);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go with Creating a Customized LinearLayout class. Refer the link for some sample ideas.

[How can I add a TextView to a LinearLayout dynamically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203506/how-can-i-add-a-textview-to-a-linearlayout-dynamically-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **SpannableStringBuilder** and **TextAppearanceSpan**. Example code:

```
        List<String> manyStrings = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"name", "value", "value", "value"});
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < manyStrings.size(); i++) {
            String text;
            if (i == 0) {
                text = manyStrings.get(i) + ": ";
            } else if (i == manyStrings.size() - 1) {
                text = manyStrings.get(i);
            } else {
                text = manyStrings.get(i) + ", ";
            }

            if (i == 0) {
                spannableStringBuilder.append(text);
                spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(getActivity(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Large), 0, text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            } else {
                int oldLength = spannableStringBuilder.length();
                spannableStringBuilder.append(text);
                spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(getActivity(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Small), oldLength, spannableStringBuilder.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }

        textView.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
```

Read more about **SpannableStringBuilder** and **TextAppearanceSpan**:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TextAppearanceSpan.html