# android dynamically create TextView not showing

Tags: android, view

Dynamically adding a textView into a LinearLayout:

layout XML:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </LinearLayout>
```

Java code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textView.setText("Hello World");
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

The textView did not show up. miss anything? Thanks.

### UPDATE

Thanks for the answers. it works even without the layoutParams.

The issue is that the LinearLayout is in the middle of a UI view tree, and the following is needed:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="mypackage.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main
```

for a Navigation Drawer activity.

Answer (score 1):

add layoutParams.
try this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
textView.setText("Hello World");
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a 1LinearLayout.LayoutParams`to the`TextView` 
look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4203731/1130568)