# How can I create a TextView programmatically in a Linear Layout?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a TextView programmatically in a LinearLayout. The program includes a checking system to check if its been added already and the prompt for creating the textview is an option in a spinner. Here is the full onClick method for the spinner

```
public void onClick(String Ingredient, int i) {

            Toast.makeText(Kitchen.super.getContext(), "Selected "+Ingredient, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(Ingredient.equals(tomatoSauce.name)) {

                if (tomatoSauce.init == 0){

                    tomatoSauce.init = 1;
                    TextView one = new TextView(getContext());
                    one.setText(Ingredient);
                    mainll.addView(one);

                }


            } else if(Ingredient.equals(chicken.name)) {

                chicken.init = 1;

            } else if(Ingredient.equals(olives.name)){

                olives.init  = 1;

            }

        }
```

The Linear layout is identified from the xml layout when the app is started in a separate method.

```
final LinearLayout mainll = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main);
```

The app crashes upon selecting Tomato Sauce from the menu despite the lack of identified coding errors. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: refer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204852/android-add-a-textview-to-linear-layout-programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Add a textview to linear layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204852/android-add-a-textview-to-linear-layout-programmatically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a TextView to a LinearLayout dynamically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203506/how-can-i-add-a-textview-to-a-linearlayout-dynamically-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

Try to add below lines of code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout =  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_id);

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("hallo hallo");
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

linearLayout.addView(tv);
```