# How do I make my Bottom Sheet Dialog dynamic?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-bottomsheetdialog

it's the first time I am trying to implement a BottomSheetDialog into my Android Studio project. In order to get a little bit more familiar with the process I tried following this tutorial on Youtube: https://youtu.be/hfoXhiMTc0c. In my actual Java Class, the BottomSheet is activated when I am scanning an NFC-Chip containing different information. However I am not able to display the information from the Chip dynamicly on the Sheet. I guess that is due to the Sheet being static? How would I be able to display the information from the chip which is already stored in a variable in my Java class to be displayed in a textfield of the BottomSheet?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

here's the code snippet of the java class where the BottomSheet is extended:

````
final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(

                Scan.this, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme
        );
        View bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                .inflate(
                        R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet,
                        (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetContainer)

                );
        bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.addToCloset).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView);
        bottomSheetDialog.show();```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with BottomSheetDialog. But,

```
        View bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
            .inflate(
                    R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet,
                    (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetContainer)

            );
```

You should be able to replace above code with,

```
    View bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
        .inflate(
                R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet,
                null

        );
```

Now go to layout_bottom_sheet.xml layout file. According to your code it should have a linear layout with no id. Give it a id. I'll take that id as "test_ll".

Now below the above code you can,

```
LinearLayout ll = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.test_ll);
```

After that you can add views dynamically to ll. For adding views dynamically to LinearLayout refer,

[Add text view to Linear layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203506/how-to-add-a-textview-to-a-linearlayout-dynamically-in-android)

**Edit:**

If you want to work with Views inside LinearLayout, you can do it by,

```
View view = ll.findViewById(R.id.view_id);
```

If your textview is in the ll,

```
TextView textView1 = ll.findViewById(R.id.tvcolor);       
textView1.setText("Hello!!");
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! Everything except one thing is working now. The link you kindly sent me is not quite fitting for my problem since I am just trying to access an already existing TextView of the .xml file and not trying to create a new one. I tried using :
```TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcolor);
      textView1.setText("Hello!!");```
However, when trying to run the code the application is just crashing:(. Any idea on how to fix?

Comment: Does that textview is in the LinearLayout?

Comment: Check the edit section of my answer. It might solve your problem.